# Typescript 2.x: How to fix "cannot find name error"

Tags: typescript2.0, gulp-typescript

I'm using gulp to transcript typescript files.

This is the gulp task:

```
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
 var tsResult = tsProject.src()
  .pipe(ts(tsProject));

  return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
});
```

In my project folder is a tsconfig.json:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
 "sourceMap": true,
 "target": "es5",
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "noImplicitAny": false
},
 "exclude": [
 "node_modules",
 "build"
 ]
}
```

I would like to use typescript packages in node_modules/@types, so i have installed them with npm.

But it doesn't work. I always get messages like

error TS2304: Cannot find name 'angular'

What is wrong? How can i get the reason?

Answer (score -1):

I think i have found the reason. I was using gulp-typescript 2.14.0
After the update to 3.0.2 the gulp task works fine.